# Oracle sql developer doesn't run commit command on worksheet

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, commit

[image: Error desc]
I'm using oracle sql developer version 19.c. When I run the *"COMMIT;"* command in worksheet the application says;

```
Unknown Command: COMMIT
```

**The query**

```
update employees_copy A 
set A.salary = (SELECT B.SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES B
                WHERE A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID)
            WHERE A.DEPARTMENT_ID = 100;
```

when i check in oracle sql dev. app it shows the right answer but when i check in sqlplus command prompt shows old value.

I tried session exit and login again but did't change the value.

Comment: please update your quesiton and include what you're running, are you running 'commit' in the worksheet or are you using the COMMIT button on the toolbar?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith im runnig "COMMIT;" command in worksheet

Comment: I suspect you've either just misspelled it, or used a similar-looking character - retype it, or copy and paste from the text on this page, and see if there is a difference. Otherwise, this might be a rare occasion where a screenshot could be useful...

Comment: @AlexPoole you can check the screenshot, hope it helps to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document I was reading wrote the command like 'COMMIT' uppercase.
So I tried to write lowercase 'commit' then it worked.
For example you write query in oracle sql developer app.

*step 1* : write your query

```
update employees_copy A 
set A.salary = 2*(SELECT B.SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES B
                WHERE A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID)
                WHERE A.DEPARTMENT_ID = 100;
```

*step 2* : you can commit your changes to database

```
commit;
```

UPDATE

[image]

I don't know what's the issue maybe it's about setup or something else.

Comment: While your change might have solved your problem, I'm pretty sure that case sensitivity is not the real issue here. It's more likely there was some type of invisible or unprintable character causing parsing problems.